# Javafx: Retrieve observableList individual elements from ScheduledService and bind them individually to different properties

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to scrape google finance. The `getStockInfoFromGoogle` method stores two strings: (1) stock Name and (2) closing price into an `ObservableList<String>`. This works fine.

Then I tried to run this method in the background using `ScheduledService` and thus, `priceService` should return an `ObservableList<String>`.

**Problem occurs** when I try to retrieve the `ObservableList<String>` from ScheduledService method, as I am not able to individually extract the strings from the list and associate them with the `lastValueProperty()` and **bind** that to the closingPrice property.

How should I solve this problem? (I want to retain `lastValueProperty()` here).

```
public class Trade{
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper stockName;
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper closingPrice;
private final ScheduledService<ObservableList<String>> priceService = new ScheduledService<ObservableList<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<ObservableList<String>> createTask(){
        return new Task<ObservableList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Number call() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                  return getStockInfoFromGoogle();
            }
        };
    }
};

// constructor
public Trade(){
    priceService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(100));
    priceService.setOnFailed(e -> priceService.getException().printStackTrace());
    this.closingPrice = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(0);
    this.stockName = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");

    // this is the part where things goes wrong for the two properties below
    this.closingPrice.bind(Double.parseDouble(priceService.lastValueProperty().get().get(1)));
    this.stockName.bind(priceService.lastValueProperty().get().get(0));

}

public ObservableList<String> getStockInfoFromGoogle() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
    ObservableList<String> output = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    // do some web scraping
    output.add(googleStockName);
    output.add(googleClosingPrice);

    return output;
```

}

Comment: Why would you use a list here, instead of creating a class to represent the data?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example please? So I can build on top of that. Because my concern is how can I reference this new class's property in `ScheduledService`? Would I need multiple `ScheduledService` s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks pretty confused, as the `Trade` class seems to be both encapsulating a trade (name and price) but also seems to be managing the service (which just updates a single trade?).

Anyway, using a `List` here is not the way to go, you should create a class to encapsulate the data you get back from the service:

```
class TradeInfo {

    private final String name ;
    private final double price ;

    public TradeInfo(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.price = price ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price ;
    }
}
```

Now make your `ScheduledService` a `ScheduledService<TradeInfo>`, etc, and you can do

```
public TradeInfo getStockInfoFromGoogle() throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    // do some web scraping
    return new TradeInfo(googleStockName, googleClosingPrice);

}
```

Now create the bindings:

```
this.closingPrice.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
    priceService.getLastValue().getPrice(),
    priceService.lastValueProperty());
this.stockName.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() ->
    priceService.getLastValue().getName(),
    priceService.lastValueProperty());
```

(You may need to deal with the case where `priceService.getLastValue()` is `null`.)

Comment: Yes. My trade manages the ScheduledService and hence just updates a single trade. Would you say this is not an ideal approach and why(disadvantage)? Can you explain in words how would you go about this differently, so I can picture the design in my mind ?

Comment: I guess that works... I guess I was assuming the "name" of a trade was fixed for any given trade, but perhaps I just don't understand the context.

Comment: The name of a trade is just a stock name. So depending on the symbol input by the user, the stock name will change accordingly. Will implement your code asap, as i need to get some rest and get ready for work tomorrow. Sorry about this.

Comment: just want to ask: since `ScheduledService` calls `getStockInfoFromGoogle` every 10 seconds and run it in the background, would this consume a lot of memory because we are essentially creating a new `TradeInfo` object every time ?

Comment: But you discard them every time, so they are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was just thinking from an optimization and efficiency point of view that maybe I could create the tradeInfo object first and keep set the name and price afterwards.

Comment: everytime I run the program, it creates a null exception error. do you know how should I overcome this?

Comment: I tried writing a try catch statement. But it was still giving me errors. How should I overcome this ?

Comment: As I said at the end of the answer, just put a null check in the computation of the binding.